# Añadir definición

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]Por favor, alguien me puede ayudar?.
Tengo el siguiente script de javascript, y quisiera añadir que según la edad, me diera si es mayor de edad o es menor de edad, o si es un bebe:
He probado varias cosas y como estoy empezando no me salgo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Fechas-Mi edad</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" id="miedad" name="miedad">
        <button type="button" onclick="edad();">Calcular</button>
        <p id="edadcalculada"></p>
        <p id="soyun">Soy Un:</p>
        <hr/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function edad() {
        var fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById('miedad').value;
        var fechaNace = new Date(fechaNacimiento);
        var fechaActual = new Date()
        var mes = fechaActual.getMonth();
        var dia = fechaActual.getDate();
        var anyo = fechaActual.getFullYear();
        fechaActual.setDate(dia);
        fechaActual.setMonth(mes);
        fechaActual.setFullYear(anyo);
        var edad = Math.floor(((fechaActual - fechaNace) / (1000 * 60 * 
    60 
* 24) / 365));
        document.getElementById('edadcalculada').innerHTML = 'La edad es: ' 
+ edad + ' Años';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta seria la parte de html:

Comment: Hola, si es posible, podría subir el documento HTML, y es, cualquier cosa me decís, Muchas garcias

Comment: Hola @Vicente, no acabo de entender el problema, ¿ qué es lo que no consigues exactamente ? Aparentemente con 2 in-then-else encadenados sobre la variable `edad` tendrías lo que pides, por lo que supongo que no lo estoy entendido del todo.

Comment: Hola, añadí imagen, garcias

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que no lo haya entendido del todo, pero en principio con un par de `if-thren-else` lo tendrías, debes añadirlo al final del método `edad()`:

```
   const LIMITE_EDAD_BEBE = 4;
   const LIMITE_EDAD_ADULTA = 18;

   if (edad < LIMITE_EDAD_BEBE) {
       document.getElementById('soyun').innerHTML = 'Soy un: bebé';
   } else if (edad < LIMITE_EDAD_ADULTA) {
       document.getElementById('soyun').innerHTML = 'Soy un: joven';
   } else {
       document.getElementById('soyun').innerHTML = 'Soy un: adulto';
   }
```

**EDITADO:** Cambio del identificador a "soyun"

Comment: Hoa Roberto, lo pruebo.

Comment: Creo que no me esta funcionando, si pudiera subir el documento tendría mas sentido, o es posible también que no me haya explicado bien. Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer copy-paste del documento html y pegarlo en la pregunta, eso ayudaría

Comment: Ya esta, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Funciona, Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, @Vicente , si te ha sido útil, marca la respuesta como correcta, eso ayudará a otros compañeros.

Comment: Hola, marcada la verificación, espero haberlo hecho correctamente, Muchas gracias.